# Как установить миниатюру поста из фронтенда?

Tags: wordpress

для создания поста из фронтенда есть такое поле

```
<input type="file" name="pictures[]" multiple="multiple">
```

с возможностью загрузки нескольких картинок. как установить миниатюру поста?

в php:

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
$meta_name_img = "ad_img";
$count = 0;

foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $count++;
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = basename($_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key]);
        @copy($tmp_name, ABSPATH.'wp-content/uploads/'.$name);
        $ad_meta_img_new = "ad_img".$count;
        add_post_meta($post_id, $ad_meta_img_new, get_site_url().'/wp-content/uploads/'.$name); 
    }
}
        $attach_id_img = media_handle_upload('ad_img1', $post_id ); 
        set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $attach_id_img);
```

Подскажите, почему не работает?
в html вывожу миниатюру с помощью

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

Comment: Можно весь код с использванием the_post_thumbnail(); ? Попробуйте указывать стандартные параметры `<?php the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr ); ?>`(размер, атрибуты). 
В общем посмотрите что возвращает хук, так как:
Ничего - выводит на экран строку. Функция выводит на экран html код картинки или пустое значение (null), если картинки не существует.
Код загрузки у вас правильный.